# Уведомление пользователей через определенное время

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Всем привет.

Никак не могу понять как сделать.
К примеру, пользователь написал пост 2017-12-03 19:20:25 и оставил его не опубликовав.
Нужно через сутки его уведомить о том, что публикация осталась не опубликованной.
Если нет реакции, то, скажем, через 5 дней повторно уведомить.
Если опять реакции нет, то удаляем эти записи еще через 5 дней.

Грубо говоря выбираются юзеры за вчера(правильно ли это?)

```
SELECT user_id, date_added FROM users WHERE date_added >= (CURDATE()-1) AND date_added < CURDATE()
```

К примеру, их уведомил, дополнительно отметив это в в таблице как-то. Типа статуса добавить, скажем notity_status(1 - уведомили 1 раз, 2 - уведомили через пять дней), чтобы понимать какой статус вообще у поста юзера.

Но вот что-то мне кажется я не правильно мыслю. Как бы не оставались записи в БД.
Может кто-то делал что-то подобное и знает уже схему опробованную? Буду благодарен за советы и помощь)

Comment: Называется `cron`. Будет периодически запускаться скрипт, который воплощает ваш алгоритм, и он будет делать эту работу

Comment: @ArchDemon это само собой. Не в ручную же) Вопрос не в том, что будет запускать скрипты, а в том как эти скрипты правильно сделать. Правильные запросы по времени, правильная обработка дат и т.д..

Comment: А почему вы делаете это полями статуса на основной таблице, а не отдельной таблицей Task/Notify/Event?? При создании записи (черновика) делаете вставку в таблицу уведомлений, когда уведомление обработано -- удаляете событие. Единственно, меня вот эта логика смущает: у вас не одно событие, а цепочка событий "когда первое закончилось -- выставить второе"

Comment: @AK Я пока поля статусов не делал. На основной думал просто, чтобы не подключать вторую таблицу или не делать доп. запросы. Если для решения нужно будет отдельную таблицу статусов, то конечно заведу ее. Меня вот цепочка это напрягает. Просто боюсь, что где-то проскочит через дату\время и запись будет мервой лежать в БД, пока ее иным способом не удалят.